# Respond to Slack Action in a thread

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've been using Slack actions API and can't figure out how to use `response_url` to send a reply in the original message's thread.

The option with `chat.postMessage` doesn't really work as it requires manually adding the bot to channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer I received from the support is:

If you want to respond in the thread, you need to set the `response_type` to `in_channel` and the `thread_ts` value to be the ts value sent with the interaction payload.

More information about [responding to actions in thread](https://vadymhimself.medium.com/respond-to-slack-action-on-a-thread-slack-interactive-messages-api-d7aa9357efe6)